# Netbeans 7.1.2 icon position on buttons

Tags: java, netbeans

we are using Netbeans 7.1.2 and we have our icons on buttons. But we also want text on the button.

The buttons are large (300, 60), the icons are small(50,50) We want to change the default position of the icon on the button, for example Icon to the left and text on the button to the right.

Can't find any obvious solution to this on the design pallete, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please this question is about SWT or Swing ?

Comment: @mKorbel Neither, I'm guessing it's about the netbeans platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button have to be able to accommodate both the icon and text

You need to Write the Text first, then you add the Icon, you see the Icon move to the left and the text to the right [image]

The above image-screen is an example of the outcome if you add the text first then add the image second

if you want to switch the text to the left-side you can use horizontalTextPosition and Horizontal Alignment

here is the out come of that [image: Text on the leftside]

Right click >>>properties click on either >>>**horizontalTextPosition** >>>>**HorizontalAlignment** to adjust  to you liking

If you are creating small icons with text,  you can use the `margin` to make  the button smaller.

Right click on the button and go to properties select **margin** sit to **[1, 1, 1, 1]** or lower by inserting negative numbers